# Updating span inner html with jQuery .html not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update a span with the value of a range input as it is being slided. It works in Chrome and Firefox but in IE (Tried both 10 & 11). There's no error in console, the span inner html is just blank. I tried with .text instead of .html but no luck. What is happening here?

```
function onRangeInput(myobj) {
        $(myobj).val();
        var theid= $(myobj).attr('id');
        var spanid = theid + "_span";
       $("#" + spanid).html($(myobj).val());
    }
```

Okay, upon further looking, I guess this code is fine and there's something wrong in the way I am calling the fucntion. Here's the html,

```
<input type="range" id="rangefirst" name="rangefirst" min="0" max="100" value="51" onChange="rangeChanged(this)" oninput="onRangeInput(this)"/> 
<span id="rangefirst_span"></span>
```

On Chrome and FF the function is getting called when the slider is moved. IE ignores the event. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this **not** deserves a downvote. Why?

Comment: Ca you create a fiddle? I can then test it on my IE?

Comment: You have an error here: `var spanid = theid = + "_span";` remove the `=` extra beetween `theid` and `+ "_span"`

Comment: @tomloprod I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine people did because this is a sumple syntax error which can be discovered by checking the console when you run the script.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Perhaps that is the reason; although I do not think it deserves a negative. Rather an explanatory comment and request the closure of the question ....

Comment: @ tomloprod. That's not it. It got there while I was formatting the code in here asking the question. Like I mentioned I am not getting an error in the console. I made the typo while posting the question, it is not there in actual code.

Comment: @redGREENblue Ok, don't worry. May you write your code inside a JSFiddle or similar? This make easiest things.

Comment: The first line of function doesn't do anything. Have you logged the returned value of `val` method? I'm sure it returns `undefined` and `html` works as getter.

Comment: @Vohuman Well actually the first line does things, but its useless the way he uses it.

Comment: @David Ok. Let me rectify it.  The first line of the function _effectively_ doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle for your question last update. `oninput` **is not supported in IE 10**; you can use something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="range" id="rangefirst" name="rangefirst" min="0" max="100" value="51"/> 
<span id="rangefirst_span"></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#rangefirst').on("change mousemove", function() {
    onRangeInput(this);  
});

function onRangeInput(myobj) {
    var theid= $(myobj).attr('id');
    var spanid = theid + "_span";
    $("#" + spanid).html($(myobj).val());
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/L5Lqafus/2/

More information for `oninput` bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=853670

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am calling the function incorrectly. Have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. My bad for not including the HTML code in the beginning.

Comment: Don't worry. Glad to have helped.